# Cannot infer type-variable(s) generics issue in Java

Tags: java, generics, types

This question may have some similar ones, but I hope you can look at the code structure here and provide some insight.  *I believe this either demonstrates a very subtle user error, or a very subtle unaddressed issue in the Java type system.*  This is a case in which Java struggles to infer the type of  an argument passed into a method with the error message:

```
java: method process in class Usage cannot be applied to given types;
  required: OuterWrapper<C,InnerWrapper<C>>
  found: RealOuterWrapper
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) C
    (argument mismatch; RealOuterWrapper cannot be converted to OuterWrapper<C,InnerWrapper<C>>)
```

One interesting detail is that very similar code (listed at the bottom) does compile and run.

**Usage.java:**

```
public static <C extends Model> void process (OuterWrapper<C, InnerWrapper<C>> wrapper) {
    ;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    process(new RealOuterWrapper());
}
```

**OuterWrapper.java:**

```
public interface OuterWrapper <T extends Model, D extends InnerWrapper<T> >{}
```

**RealOuterWrapper.java:**

```
public class RealOuterWrapper implements OuterWrapper<RealModel, RealInnerWrapper>{}
```

**InnerWrapper.java:**

```
public interface InnerWrapper <T extends Model>{}
```

**RealInnerWrapper.java:**

```
public interface RealInnerWrapper extends InnerWrapper<RealModel>{}
```

**Model.java:**

```
public interface Model {}
```

**RealModel.java:**

```
public class RealModel implements Model {}
```

---

This code fails to compile.  However, this code compiles successfully:

---

**Usage.java:**

```
public class Usage {
    public static <C extends Model> void process (Wrapper<C,C> wrapper) {
        ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        process(new RealWrapper());
    }
}
```

**Wrapper.java:**

```
public interface Wrapper <A extends Model,B extends Model>{}
```

**RealWrapper.java:**

```
public class RealWrapper implements Wrapper<RealModel,RealModel>{}
```

**Model.java:**

```
public interface Model {}
```

**RealModel.java:**

```
public class RealModel implements Model {}
```

Finally, if this wall of text is too hard to reason about, [here is my GitHub repo](https://github.com/asegs/generics-mismatch) containing these files!

---

Edit: Rewriting `RealInnerWrapper` as a class that implements `InnerWrapper`, I added

**Usage.java:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    process(new RealOuterWrapper());
    process2(new RealInnerWrapper());
}
public static void process2 (InnerWrapper<RealModel> wrapper) {
    ;
}
```

However, the latter method `process2` gives no such error, which implies a `RealInnerWrapper()` is an `InnerWrapper<RealModel>`.

Comment: The problem is that even though `RealInnerWrapper` extends `InnerWrapper<RealModel>`, that doesn't mean that an `OuterWrapper<RealModel, RealInnerWrapper>` is the same as an `OuterWrapper<RealModel, InnerWrapper<RealModel>>`.  This is very similar to the old `List<Dog>` vs `List<Animal>` question, which I'll now try to find.

Comment: OK, I believe this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265) but I'm not going to vote, because my vote is a hammer.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem To demonstrate in this case: add `void foo(D d);` to `OuterWrapper`, add `@Override public void foo(RealInnerWrapper d) { }` to `RealOuterWrapper`, then add `wrapper.foo(new InnerWrapper<C>() {});` to `process`. Then if you force `main` to go through with `process((OuterWrapper<RealModel, InnerWrapper<RealModel>>)(Object)new RealOuterWrapper());` [you get a `ClassCastException`](https://godbolt.org/z/7av4dxocd). Therefore the call to `process` without the cast is in fact unsafe. OP probably wants to add some wildcards somewhere...

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - the way I see the signature for `process` is as requiring an `OuterWrapper` with the parameters of some `Model` and an `InnerWrapper` wrapping a model of that same type.  `RealOuterWrapper` takes a `RealModel` and a `RealInnerWrapper`, which wraps a `RealModel`.  Am I misunderstanding the meaning of this type signature?  Or is there some other detail at play?  And I may close this as a duplicate, but I am curious about the semantics here first.

Comment: And see my last edit, I would think that if `RealModel` is a `RealModel`, and `RealInnerWrapper` is an `InnerWrapper<RealModel>`, then why is `OuterWrapper<RealModel, RealInnerWrapper>` not an `OuterWrapper<RealModel, InnerWrapper<RealModel>>`?  Thank you!

Comment: @Aaron Jon Skeet explains that really well in his answer to the question that I linked to in my second comment.

Comment: You could try something like `public static <C extends Model> void process (OuterWrapper<C, ? extends InnerWrapper<C>> wrapper)` - this may give you what you want.  The point is that the `OuterWrapper<RealModel, RealInnerWrapper>` can't wrap things that are just `InnerWrapper<RealModel>`, which means that you mustn't go assigning one to a variable whose type is `OuterWrapper<RealModel, InnerWrapper<RealModel>>` - which is fundamentally what you're trying to do.

Comment: So in that case, we are saying `?` = anything that extends `InnerWrapper<C>`, or anything that extends `InnerWrapper<RealModel>`.  Yep, I see the similarity between these questions now, although I am not convinced that the `?` should be required here, as that seems like the implied behavior.  I will sit down and read this over a cup of coffee tomorrow morning and try to get my head in the place where this seems logical.  Thanks @DawoodibnKareem.

Comment: It certainly takes time for all this stuff to settle in the brain.  To answer your question, `C` would get resolved to `RealModel`, so the effect is the same.  My suggestion is to try it with the `?` and see if it makes the problem go away.  Sometimes with these things, you end up with an error somewhere else when you make such a change.

Comment: Oh yeah - to be clear, that "fixed" it.  I feel like that's just telling it to use anything that is descended from `InnerWrapper<RealModel>`, which I feel should be implicit always?  As put by OP in the question you linked: "[Why do] I have to explicitly tell the method to accept a list of any subclass of Animal"?

Comment: Oh!  You're saying I can't just give it an `OuterWrapper` containing any arbitrary `InnerWrapper` and then reference that `InnerWrapper`, the `?` signifies a certain implementation of `InnerWrapper` which is used throughout?